# PowerBI, Power Query disable SSL certificate verification

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

There exists no resource online demonstrating how to turn off SSL certificate verification.  Postman, C#, and virtually everything else has an option to turn this off.  I am wondering if PowerBI has the same.  If not, what alternatives are there to permanently turn off SSL certification in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

This option does not exist. To disable it you need to disable certificate validation in .Net, which you can do by setting the [servicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/servicepointmanager-element-network-settings) element in an app.config or machine.config file.

Keep in mind that, without certificate validation, SSL/TLS loses much of its security benefits.